# Javascript Canvas and fonts

Tags: javascript

When working on a canvas with javascript, is it possible to use ctx.fillText to return an input value?

something like this I guess:

```
(html)
    (Customize:(input id="custom" value="Default Message" /)
    (p)(button onclick="msg()")Try it(/button)(/p)
    (canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500")
    (/canvas)
(/html)

(script)

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"); 
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var message
message = document.getElementById("custom").value;

function msg(){
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
    ctx.font = "italic 800 30px Verdana";
    ctx.fillText(message, 485, 245, 1000);
}

msg();

(/script)
```

So whatever the user types into the input will be drawn on the canvas when "Try It" is clicked. Is this possible or am I way off track?

Comment: What did you try? Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try your code? It's essentially fine, except that you need to determine the value of `message` within the `msg()` function so that it can change when the user changes it and, you should either pick a new color, or add color to the canvas so you can SEE it:

```
<body>
Customize:<input id="custom" value="Default Message" />
    <p><button onclick="msg()">Try it</button></p>
    <canvas style="background-color:#cccccc" id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500">
    </canvas>
    <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"); 
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var message;

    function msg(){
    message=document.getElementById('custom').value;
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
    ctx.font = "italic 800 30px Verdana";
    ctx.fillText(message, 100, 245, 1000);
    }

    msg();
    </script>
</body>
```